# Difficult to explain delay in TcpClient

Tags: c#, tcp

I am receiving large amounts of data (frequent small messages) from an ITCH protocol server.

My app works well in that all messages are correctly parsed. However, I get mysterious delays when ( as far as I can tell) nothing is happening except code is setting at "ReadByte".

```
TcpClient simpleTcp = new TcpClient(serverAddress, serverPort);
simpleTcp.NoDelay = true;
simpleTcp.Client.NoDelay = true;                   
simpleTcp.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = 1024; 
simpleTcp.ReceiveBufferSize = 1024;
simpleTcp.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;


NetworkStream tcpStream = simpleTcp.GetStream();

//Send login and subscciptions...

while (true)
{
    lock (TcpLock)
    {
        int abyte = tcpStream.ReadByte();
        try
        {
            LbTime.Stopwatch.Restart();
            Console.WriteLine("\n>>>>GetMessage Start: " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff") + " " + LbTime.Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("F0"));

            //Process message (Complex)

            Console.WriteLine(">>>>GetMessage End: " + LbTime.Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("F0") + " Now: " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff") + "\n");
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw;
        } 
    }
  }
```

I show the time at beginning and end of processing. However, when I get a later message - the time differs greatly from the time buried in the message received. I.e. I am receiving the message late.

I have tried this on 2 machines, the latter had nothing else running on it, and I still get mysterious delays sometimes.

I undertand this is very difficult to help with as I am unable to provide a working example because it is dependent on connecting to a private ITCH protocol server.

If any one can shed some light that would be great.

Comment: How late is "late"? It takes time for data to get across a network, and there could be a delay at the sending side due to buffering anyway.

Comment: 200+ ms. This is on a xConnect very fast internal link

Comment: Okay, sounds like it could be Nagle's algorithm with buffering at the sending side. Or just difference in system clocks - two system clocks being 200ms apart is very believable.

Comment: Yes, but we are have our clock sync to +/- 1 ms. I think it is to do with Tcp. The nagle should be sorted as I have set NoDelay=true. Is that right?

Comment: Well that's on the *receiving* side... it's the *sending* side where NoDelay would make a difference. Have you looked at what's happening with Wireshark or something similar?

Comment: I use the same tcpStream for sending and receiving. So I have NoDelay would affect both right? I don't no how to use wireshark - so no I haven't checked that

Comment: No, because it's the *server* that's deciding to when send the packets. I suggest you learn about Wireshark now - that will take the client code out of the picture.

Comment: Windows is using timers to move data between ethernet card and application (not interrupts).  So latency can occur when operating system is busy and 200 msec is reasonable.

Comment: In finance 200ms is a very long time. I don't have issues with other high-freq data connections (FIX). Just this new TCP one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This delay remained inexplicable to me. However, several answers to similar questions suggested that using raw Sockets would be better.

I replacde all my Stream and NetworkStreams with Socket and now the Socket.Receive() works without any ad-hoc delays.